# Format a textbox like "0.00"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to format a textbox like "0.00" using jQuery or JavaScript? If I enter value `59`, then it should become `59.00`. If I enter value as `59.20`, then it should be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery, assuming you have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="someInput" name="something"/>
```

You can use this:

```
$('#someInput').blur(function() {
    var floatValue = parseFloat(this.value);
    if (!isNaN(floatValue)) { // make sure they actually entered a number
        this.value = floatValue.toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

Whenever the input loses focus, the value will be converted always have 2 decimal places, as long as the user entered something that can be parsed into a number.

Comment: `isFinite` is not enough, it will wrongly return `true` with an empty string or a string containing only white-space characters (since both coerce to `0`), e.g.: `isFinite('') == true;`, `isFinite('\t\n ') == true`, for those cases, the input will end with `'NaN'` as value.

Comment: @CMS Ah, I will revert it back to my earlier version of the answer then:  `parseFloat` first, then check `isNaN`.